Any good steps to debug google sign-in button not even rendering?
I am following the [documentation here] (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/client-library)
I put this code in TWO apps(one working, one not working) at the end of the body in my index.html for my angular application
        <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>
    </body>
</html>

I add the following html in both apps
  <div id="g_id_onload"
       data-client_id="301124526277-kkp3v1t9479jnmgqdeh2rerk9nabmo94.apps.googleusercontent.com"
       data-context="signin"
       data-ux_mode="popup"
       data-login_uri="/postGoogleToken"
       data-nonce=""
       data-auto_prompt="false">
  </div>

  <div class="g_id_signin"
       data-type="standard"
       data-shape="pill"
       data-theme="outline"
       data-text="signin_with"
       data-size="large"
       data-logo_alignment="left">
  </div>

Although, I tweaked the html in my non-working app to see where the divs would be and to make sure they had room ->
<div class="flex-auto h-20 w-10 border-2 border-blue-900"
     id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="309934505077-kkp3v1t9479jnmgqdeh2rerk9nab94mo.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="popup"
     data-login_uri="/postGoogleToken"
     data-nonce=""
     data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>

<div class="flex-auto g_id_signin h-20 w-80 border-2 border-red-600"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="pill"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>

In the working app, the login button renders a very long button 100% of width and then re-renders into a better normal google sign-in button.
In my app that does not work, the button does not render at all.
picture of my working app

picture of my app that does not work (no google sign-in button) with red and blue borders around the google divs to see if at least the viewing area was big enough..

My developer tools console shows no javascript errors
How can I tell if google's login button script even ran?  How do I debug this issue further?  Currently, the first thing I did was create the base angular app from angular 18 generator with new project and that worked.    I am wondering if there is a quicker way as trimming down this gigantic app or building up the base app does not seem like it could be done in a reasonable time-frame.  Any type of logging with google sign in buttons?
I tried the stuff above.

This code fixes the issue for google javascript to run again and render button.  This was very difficult to find so posting here for next person
declare global {
    interface Window {
        onGoogleSignIn: (response: any) => void;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'google-button',
    templateUrl: './google-button.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    animations: fuseAnimations,
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
    ],
})
export class GoogleButtonComponent implements OnInit {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor(
    ) {}

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // @ Lifecycle hooks
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * On init
     */
    ngOnInit(): void {
        const body = <HTMLDivElement>document.body;
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client';
        script.async = true;
        script.defer = true;
        body.appendChild(script);
        window.onGoogleSignIn= this.onGoogleSignIn.bind(this);
    }

    onGoogleSignIn(response: any): void {
        console.log("signed in");
    }

}

